# PS Liquify show backdrop not working

Tags: photoshop-effects

Having this issue where I can't view all layers as the backdrop in Photoshop 2021. I can only see the layer I'm manipulating.

"Show backdrop" is checked
"All layers" selected
Mode: Behind
Opacity 100
No masks are being used

Is there something I'm overlooking?

Running Photoshop version 22.4.2
Nvidia GTX 1660
Windows 10

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Reduce the opacity.  100% is fully opaque, so you won't be able to see through it.